# Price filter not showing on layered navigation

Tags: layered-navigation

Price filter not working even I have also selected "Filterable (with results)" in price attribute

[image: only title showing]

[image]

Comment: Please check error log, so can easily find the solution. If you can't  get any solution then share your error log.